# .htaccess redirect to file

Tags: .htaccess, redirect, redirect-loop

I have to humble myself and ask for some guidance on a topic I thought I understood.  I am struggling with a 301 redirect issue, and hope someone not engrossed in this issue can help me see the light.

My domain once used folders as the primary product target, ie, domain.com/prod1, domain.com/prod2, etc, but recently changed the targets to .php files, ie, domain.com/prod1.php, domain.com/prod2, etc.  It seems I am having a problem since my source and targets have the same name, and I am selecting a wildcard which causes redirect loops.  My normal redirects are working, but I haven't been able to find the secret sauce to redirecting these non-existant folders to their respective php files. My latest attempt is as follows:

```
RedirectMatch 301 ^/prod1 http://domain.com/prod1.php
```

Maybe it's just too late, but I could really use some help getting (me) straightened out.  Thanks!

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You could add the end of line to your matching regular expression: `^/prod1(/)?$`

Comment: And I do know the (/) grouping is redundant ;)

Comment: Yup, I was hoping it was that simple.  Thanks for the quick clarification, all is well in my crazy brain once again!

Answer (score 2):

Your regular expression matches your target (`^/prod1` matches `/prod1.php`). So you can either add a terminating character to your regexp or use mod_rewrite and a condition.

```
RedirectMatch 301 ^/prod1/?$ http://domain.com/prod1.php
```

Or:

```
RewriteEngine On
# request doesn't end with ".php"
RewriteCond %{REQUEST_URI} !\.php$
RewriteRule ^([^/]+)/?$ http://domain.com/$1.php [R=301]
```